# Float second div above first div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a canvas on `div a` and a gif image on `div b`. What I want to do is to hide my canvas without using `display: none;` by putting the `div b` over `div a`.

I achieve it before by using display none to hide `div a`. But now I want `div a`to stay there while `div b` floats above it.

This is the current scenario: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/efn9er18/1/)

Answer (score 2):

try it with position absolute on div a. note that

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

will not work here. so use 'left' and 'margin-left' to fix that.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/efn9er18/4/)

Answer (score 2):

I would wrap the two elements you want stacked in a container div and absolutely position `div .b` over `div .a`.

```css
.a, .b { 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 30px; 
    text-align: center; 
}

.wrap{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 30px; 
}

.a { 
    border: 1px solid red; 
    background: red;
}
.b { 
    border: 1px solid green; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: blue;
}

.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.xtra {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="xtra"></div>
    
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="a">div a</div>
        <div class="b">div b</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/efn9er18/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

You could `position` them both `absolute` and set z-index to `.b`.

```css
.a, .b {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.a {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
}
.b {
    border: 1px solid green;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.xtra {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="xtra"></div>
    <div class="a">div a</div>
    <div class="b">div b</div>
</div>
```